# Get timeline for multiple nodes in Overpass

Tags: overpass-api

I am trying to use the `timeline` function to get information about the history of the nodes of an area, instead of the history of a single node as shown in the documentation.

This code works, and I am able to refer to the node id in the query filter condition by using `u(id())`:

```
[bbox:45.4,9.2,45.5,9.25];
node["amenity"="vending_machine"]({{bbox}});
foreach (
  if (u(id()) == 4612313390) {
    out;
  }
);
```

I try to pass the id to `timeline`, but I get a syntax error and an additional error saying that id should be a positive integer.

```
[bbox:45.4,9.2,45.5,9.25];
node["amenity"="vending_machine"]({{bbox}});
foreach (
  timeline(node, id());
  out;
);
```

Error:

```
Error: line 4: parse error: ',' or ')' expected - '(' found.
Error: line 4: parse error: ';' expected - ')' found.
Error: line 4: static error: For the attribute "ref" of the element "timeline" the only allowed values are positive integers.
```

What is the correct way to pass an id as argument to a function like `timeline`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`timeline(node, id())` is not supported as of the current version 0.7.56:
`timeline` expects a concrete object id. It is not possible to specify the object id via some expression, like `id()`.

You can try raising an enhancement request on https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/issues

Comment: Thank you :) Is there any workaround for that? I tried to do it in two steps: ask for the nodes in a bbox and generate a requests replicating a block with `timeline` and `retro` for each node, but the request becomes too long quickly.

Comment: You can send your request via HTTP POST instead of HTTP GET, this should allow for much larger requests.